# What is the evidence for cognition being mainly confined to the brain?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy, cognition

We believe that the processes of cognition are mainly confined to the brain.

What is the evidence for that?

I understand that the brain shows increased oxygen saturation in fMRI scans while thinking intensely. Therefore, we can conclude that brain plays a role in cognition. But how do we conclude that the rest of the body plays a negligible role in it?

In other words, how can we be certain that the brain's role in cognition is not a supportive one rather than an almost exclusive one?

I know that there is enough evidence for brain having a role in cognition, however my curiosity is mainly that why do we confine it to the brain alone? In other words, how are we certain that cognition is not spread outside the brain?

Comment: I think tetraplegics generally have no troubles with cognition, so we can rule out all four limbs. There are people living without stomach, half of lungs, without kidneys, with severly shorter intestines, smaller liver, no eyes, no tongue, non-functional ears, heart-transplants ... yet all of them (can) have normal cognition ... However, even a tiny damage to the brain can lead to significant cognitive disabilities. So ... which organ do you propose as an alternative center for cognition? :)

Comment: By studying countless insults to the brain, all aspects of cognition have been identified, even pinpointed to particular parts of the brain, not only in humans but in other animals as well. We know where memory is, where speech centers/understanding speech is located, where pleasure is perceived, etc. Dogs trained to be still in MRI machines exhibit the same patterns in the same places with certain stimuli. A heart transplant (or other) doesn't make the recipient think like the donor. Look up fMRI; that maps cognition as it happens.

Comment: @Domen Thank you for your comment. That is definitely a good piece of evidence.

Comment: @vkehayas Yes, thank you. Actually, my question arose out of similar contemplations.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Thank you for your comment. Insults, injuries, and fMRI do establish that brain has a role in cognition. What I wondered was how can we be sure that it has almost exclusive role, rather than a supportive one?

Comment: @Domen Could you please add your comment as an answer? It did help me understand the reasoning behind the idea.

Comment: I have extremely good "gut intuition"... which is found in the brain. What kind of cognition is *not* found in the brain? What are you imagining any other organ can do in terms of cognition? Which organ? The liver? The heart? You've been given plenty of replies.

Comment: @vkehayas I would not say a brain in a jar cannot cognate, it is just very difficult to demonstrate cognition. Brain in jars for animals when connected to circuitry can control robots. https://www.science.org/content/article/lamprey-brain-drives-robot#:~:text=Through%20trial%20and%20error%2C%20the,or%20circle%20patterns%2C%20Fleming%20says.

Comment: Also, people that go into comas and brain death have great vital signs from all of their body, although we can see from their brain activity that it is different and causing the coma. brain death: https://www.life-source.org/latest/what-is-the-difference-between-a-coma-and-brain-death/

Comment: Who said cognition was confined to the brain (I mean, before you posted the question here)? Definitions probably vary somewhat, but most seem to include experience and sensory information as inherent components of cognition, so I'm just curious where that opening statement came from. Particularly the word "confined." This question might actually be better suited for [Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single best evidence is injury and deformity.

You can lose any other part of the body without impairing cognition but brain damage especially damage to specific parts of the brain alter or damage cognition. Losing a foot or a kidney or an eye does not suddenly make you unable to speak, but damage to the language center of the brain does. Cataloging the effects of damage to different parts of the brain has actually given a fairly decent map of what different parts of the brain do before we started scanning active brains.

https://uwmsktc.washington.edu/sites/uwmsktc/files/files/TBI_cognitive.pdf

https://www.biausa.org/brain-injury/about-brain-injury/basics/function-of-the-brain

Animal brain removed from their bodies and connected to circuitry can learn.

As for how can we be certain, we can't, that's not how science works. We can say it is extremely likely given existing evidence and there is no evidence to the contrary, to the point it can be safely assumed, but science does not deal in absolute certainty.

Comment: Thank you. The links were educative to me.

Comment: Degeneration of the muscles controlling the vocal cords will also lead to loss of speech. When you look up closely, phrenological claims such as "brain area X does Y" crumble, although certain brain areas are associated more with certain functions than others. Attaching a brain to a mechanical "body" to perform a function proves that a brain cannot affect the world and receives no sensory inputs without a body. The body is not just the hardware that runs some neural software, it determines how the brain works and provides it with its purpose. You just need both by order of evolution.

Comment: @vkehayas - "phrenological claims"? Phrenology infers characteristics from the shape of the skull, not the brain, and no normal modern person believes that. The brain would work pretty well if it had the right (and uninterrupted) conditions of nutrients, gaseous exchange, temperature, etc., but no one can come back from that to tell about it. And of course, sensory input would be gone, but that doesn't mean thinking would disappear. Insanity might ensue, but we don't know, we can't know. A quadriplegic has decreased sensory input as well, but can still think.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Do you mean that you agree with my arguments or that you missed their point? Because demanding absolute localization of cognitive functions in a one-to-one correspondence with specific brain areas is high-resolution phrenology and it's not supported by evidence. As for artificially re-creating the physiological environment that the rest of the body provides for the brain to sustain its function, you must be able to see that it re-inforces my argument, right? Lastly, does a quadriplegic's condition suggest to you that the body is not necessary for cognition? If so, how?

Comment: @vkehayas so you think a computer needs the internet to run programs just because it needs the internet to download them? As a pointed out a brain in a vat of jelly connected to nothing but wires can still learn, input is needed but a body is not the only form of input.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Unfortunately I do not have the time nor do I think this is the place to have such a discussion. If you are curious though, I encourage you to read primary research or at least something recent (last 40 years or so). On the topic of the dualism you appear to espouse, read on "embodied cognition", e.g. Damasio, Varela, Lakoff etc.

Comment: @John Imagine a computer that atrophies if it stays unplugged from power or disconnected from the internet and that can only grow if those conditions exist. Now imagine a computer that can have multiple power sources and ways to connect with other computers and grows --in a similar way to biological evolution-- according to the sources available and those that it "prefers". I encourage you to read about structural and functional plasticity during development and in adults. I do not doubt that if we try we will be able to sustain a healthy brain without the rest of the body. But **why**?

Comment: @vkehayas none of which shows cognition is not happening in the brain, it just shows that the brain needs certain conditions to operate, which well duh.  I am curious as to what you think is being argued because you don't seem to be giving any arguments against the brain being where cognition happens, just that the brain is not the only part of the body, which nobody is arguing.

Answer (score 1):

We can monitor brain waves from people in comas and brain death. Even though their organs are fine and so are their heart and limbs, their brain scan looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However, I would beg you to consider that this is only an evidence for brain having a critical role in cognition, not an almost exclusive one. I know that there is enough evidence for brain having a critical role in cognition, however my curiosity was mainly that how can we confine it to the brain alone. In other words, how can we be certain that cognition is not spread throughout the body.

Comment: To support such a claim, you need to be able to answer questions such as: "What led to coma/brain death?", "What is the result of the loss of brain function?", without invoking the rest of the body.